# How to talk about official procedures?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

> **How often do you take photographs?**
>
> Every day I'd say. I take a photo of one of my children because they
>   do something funny. Also, nowadays, I have to finish **a lot of
>   government official documents** so I use my cell phone to take pictures
>   of these documents.

By "finish government official documents" I mean print out an official tax statement and take a photo of it using my cell phone, then send it to a foreign government entity as a way to proof of my professional experience. OR submit online request for birth certificate of my new born baby.  What do you call these actions? because in my native language we have a phrase for these actions, we simply say "finish papers"!

Comment: Aside: is it wise/legal to photograph documents on a personal phone? In UK if you take your work home like that, you could find yourself in deep trouble.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why any government would care if I took a photo of my tax statement using my cell phone? I plan to travel to a western country so, it is a good idea to ask.

Comment: You have edited the question, but I seemed as though you meant photographing employer's documents on a personal phone, to take home and work on.

Answer (score 0):

"Finish" is not the right verb here. If you finish a document it means you have written all of it. Your clarification suggests what you actually mean is "send copies of official documents".  This is how you should phrase it.

> Also I use my phone to take photographs of official documents when I need to send a copy.

You are using your phone as a scanner, you could mention this

> Nowadays, I need often scans of official documents. I use my phone to take photos instead of using a scanner.